# Tabs don't fit to screen with tabmode=scrollable, Even with a Custom Tab Layout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have made a custom TabLayout with a `ViewPager` and am using the TabLayout in scrollable mode:

I need it to be scrollable as the number of dates can vary to as many as 15-20:

```
<com.example.project.recommendedapp.CustomScrollableTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout_movie"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabTextAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

The custom class i used as per another similar question: 
[TabLayout not filling width when tabMode set to 'scrollable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601414/tablayout-not-filling-width-when-tabmode-set-to-scrollable)

The **custom tablayout class** is:

```
package com.example.project.recommendedapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class CustomScrollableTabLayout extends TabLayout {
    private Context mContext;

    Point size;

    public CustomScrollableTabLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext=context;
        size = new Point();
    }

    public CustomScrollableTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext=context;
        size = new Point();
    }

    public CustomScrollableTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mContext=context;
        size = new Point();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        try {
            if (getTabCount() == 0) {
                return;
            }else {
                Display display = ((WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
                display.getSize(size);
                int width = size.x;

                Field field = TabLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mScrollableTabMinWidth");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(this, (width / getTabCount()));

                Log.d("FragmentCreate",String.valueOf(width / getTabCount()));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("FragmentCreate","Error while setting width",e);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be how Google wants it to be, unfortunately.

Comment: You might try putting your `TabLayout` inside a layout and setting gravity to center_horizontal.

Answer (score 23):

I looked all over for an answer to this exact problem. In my case I was dynamically adding and removing tabs, so I wanted it to fill the screen when there were only a few tabs, but start scrolling when there were too many rather than shrinking them or putting the titles on two lines. Using the following custom tab layout finally got it working for me. It was key to set the minimum width *before* calling super.onMeasure().

```
public class CustomTabLayout extends TabLayout {

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        ViewGroup tabLayout = (ViewGroup)getChildAt(0);
        int childCount = tabLayout.getChildCount();

        if( childCount != 0 ) { 
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            int tabMinWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels/childCount;

            for(int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i){
                tabLayout.getChildAt(i).setMinimumWidth(tabMinWidth);
            }
        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Set the tab mode to scrollable in the xml.

```
    <com.package.name.CustomTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable">
```

Comment: After spending 2 days, finally working.  This custom tab layout working perfectly.

Comment: yep. the onMeasure did the trick. I just wrap it with 
`if(childCount != 0) {

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int tabMinWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels/childCount;

        for(int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i){
            tabLayout.getChildAt(i).setMinimumWidth(tabMinWidth);
        }
}`

cause it crashes my app

Comment: this works. be sure to set `app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"` and `app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"` otherwise you do see some slight funky scrolling behaviour on the tab bar from the unaccounted for pixels

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution.

```
public class MyTabLayout extends TabLayout {    
    public MyTabLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        ViewGroup tabLayout = (ViewGroup)getChildAt(0);

        int childCount = tabLayout.getChildCount();

        int widths[] = new int[childCount+1];

        for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++){
            widths[i] = tabLayout.getChildAt(i).getMeasuredWidth();
            widths[childCount] += widths[i];
        }

        int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++){
            tabLayout.getChildAt(i).setMinimumWidth(measuredWidth*widths[i]/widths[childCount]);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution is slightly different, since I tried the one above and it didn't work on some devices. I've noticed that if all tabs are visible on the screen and if we set `tabMode` to `fixed`, `TabLayout` fills its given width. When we use `scrollable`, `TabLayout` acts like its `tabGravity` is set to `center`.

So, I calculate the sum of widths of all tabs in `TabLayout` and if it is lower than measured width I set its `tabMode` to `MODE_FIXED`, otherwise to `MODE_SCROLLABLE`:

```
public class CustomTabLayout extends TabLayout {

    private static final String TAG = CustomTabLayout.class.getSimpleName();

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (getTabCount() == 0)
            return;
        try {
            ViewGroup tabLayout = (ViewGroup)getChildAt(0);
            int widthOfAllTabs = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                widthOfAllTabs += tabLayout.getChildAt(i).getMeasuredWidth();
            }
            setTabMode(widthOfAllTabs <= getMeasuredWidth() ? MODE_FIXED : MODE_SCROLLABLE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those landing here from google like I did here is my 2021 Kotlin solution.
It achieves the following which I couldn't do from other answers:

- If not many tabs they expand to fill the whole width.
- If lots of tabs they are scrollable so they aren't squished.
- Works correctly even if tabLayout is not the full width of the screen.

To achieve this I created a subclass of `TabLayout` that overrides `onMeasure`

```
class ScalableTabLayout : TabLayout {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    )

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        val tabLayout = getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
        val childCount = tabLayout.childCount
        if (childCount != 0) {
            val widthPixels = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
            val tabMinWidth = widthPixels / childCount
            var remainderPixels = widthPixels % childCount
            tabLayout.forEachChild {
                if (remainderPixels > 0) {
                    it.minimumWidth = tabMinWidth + 1
                    remainderPixels--
                } else {
                    it.minimumWidth = tabMinWidth
                }
            }
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
    }
}
```

And then used it in my layout file:

```xml
<com.package.name.ScalableTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
    app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

both `tabMaxWidth="0dp"` and `tabMode="scrollable"` are required